# Symfony4 - Can't get assets with mobile device on local network

Tags: symfony, webpack, localhost, wamp, webpack-encore

I'm working on a Symfony 4 project with Webpack Encore for asset management.
I configured my local server with this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15864222/5158153

I can access to localhost from my Android device but it doesn't get access to any asset. 
I tried with another project (not Symfony) and it can get assets.

I think there's something I forgot with webpack config but I don't know what.

**Webpack-config.js**

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
.setPublicPath('http://localhost/tharmo/public/build')
.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
.autoProvidejQuery()
.createSharedEntry('vendor', [
    './assets/js/custom.js',
    'materialize-css',
])
.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
.enableSassLoader()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**base.html.twig**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}"
          media="screen,projection" />
```

It works correctly in Windows where Wamp server is installed but not in Android.
On Android device, if I type the url, I can get the asset so something is wrong with the way I get asset in Twig.

Comment: Try using relative path for your `.setPublicPath()`

Comment: what is the url of your non-working assets ?

Comment: http://localhost/tharmo/public/build/app.css

Comment: It works with `.setPublicPath('/tharmo/public/build')`